# Can I write entire application using NOSQL ONLY?

Tags: php, mysql, nosql, relational-database

I am planning an application that intends to store a LOT of user data. and i am quite concerned about the speed of data retrial.
I have heard a little about NOSQL and know that it provides better performance than relational databases. So I am planning to use NOSQL (Preferably MongoDB) as my primary database system.

I want to ask if its really possible to create an entire application using ONLY NOSQL or even using it as my primary database. Am i on the correct path? Do i need to use relational databases(MySQL) as well?

I am totally novice in NOSQL technologies and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: @YourCommonSense : i just a little advice

Comment: This is not a real programming question -- you can get an answer from any blog talking about their system architecture and experience with mongodb

Comment: @Soren can u please point me to such resources

Comment: The MongoDB website have a list of "In Production" use cases, and a simple search on "mongodb architecture" gives examples like this: http://sn.im/238i4zq

Comment: @Soren, thats a really good read man thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Most NoSQL database, including MongoDB scales horizontally -- that means that you will be scaling for performance by adding more machines to a MongoDB cluster so as to keep up performance when you grow your traffic.

Whether *you* can write your application using only MongoDB depends on how you architect your object model and how you do your coding -- but there are many sites which uses nothing else.

Comment: what do u mean by nothing else ? does it mean sites are using only NOSQL for entire application ?

Comment: I mean, nothing else for storage -- most people create the application using a webservices layer written in Ruby, NodeJs or Java/PHP etc -- however I think it could be possible for the adventitious to write the entire application using **just** MongoDB (or Riak) and Jquery in the browser -- however that would take some expertise and is probably not what I would recommend if you have to ask the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether they are "faster", and even if they are, I would not use that as your prime motive.  Document based db's like mongo are fundamentally *different* than SQL dbs.  You should make sure you understand the difference first, by trying them out.

Whether you can write an entire application with mongo (or SQL) depends on the application, doesn't it?  I would recommend *against* the idea of using two separate database engines in the same application unless there is some specific (and unusual) reason to do so.  Ie. the best idea is to assess your choice and choose the most appropriate **one**.

Comment: i mean not just mongo db but any other NOSQL database ?

Comment: Well, I've used couchdb (which I believe is very very similiar) enough to say you could do "anything" with it in the same sense you can do "anything" with SQL: that "anything" refers to the ends, and not the means.  Make sense?